# How to target a specific item to toggleClick on using React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, styled-components, react-hooks

I have a navbar component with that actual info being pulled in from a CMS.  Some of the nav links have a dropdown component onclick, while others do not.  I'm having a hard time figuring out how to target a specific menus index with React Hooks - currently onClick, it opens ALL the dropdown menus at once instead of the specific one I clicked on.

The prop toggleOpen is being passed down to a styled component based on the handleDropDownClick event handler.

Heres my component.

```
const NavBar = props => {
 const [links, setLinks] = useState(null);
 const [notFound, setNotFound] = useState(false);
 const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

 const fetchLinks = () => {
   if (props.prismicCtx) {
     // We are using the function to get a document by its uid
     const data = props.prismicCtx.api.query([
       Prismic.Predicates.at('document.tags', [`${config.source}`]),
       Prismic.Predicates.at('document.type', 'navbar'),
     ]);
     data.then(res => {
       const navlinks = res.results[0].data.nav;
       setLinks(navlinks);
     });
   }
   return null;
 };

 const checkForLinks = () => {
   if (props.prismicCtx) {
     fetchLinks(props);
   } else {
     setNotFound(true);
   }
 };

 useEffect(() => {
   checkForLinks();
 });

 const handleDropdownClick = e => {
   e.preventDefault();
   setIsOpen(!isOpen);
 };

 if (links) {
   const linkname = links.map(item => {
     // Check to see if NavItem contains Dropdown Children
     return item.items.length > 1 ? (
       <Fragment>
         <StyledNavBar.NavLink onClick={handleDropdownClick} href={item.primary.link.url}>
           {item.primary.label[0].text}
         </StyledNavBar.NavLink>
         <Dropdown toggleOpen={isOpen}>
           {item.items.map(subitem => {
             return (
               <StyledNavBar.NavLink href={subitem.sub_nav_link.url}>
                 <span>{subitem.sub_nav_link_label[0].text}</span>
               </StyledNavBar.NavLink>
             );
           })}
         </Dropdown>
       </Fragment>
     ) : (
       <StyledNavBar.NavLink href={item.primary.link.url}>
         {item.primary.label[0].text}
       </StyledNavBar.NavLink>
     );
   });
   // Render
   return (
     <StyledNavBar>
       <StyledNavBar.NavContainer wide>
         <StyledNavBar.NavWrapper row center>
           <Logo />
           {linkname}
         </StyledNavBar.NavWrapper>
       </StyledNavBar.NavContainer>
     </StyledNavBar>
   );
 }
 if (notFound) {
   return <NotFound />;
 }
 return <h2>Loading Nav</h2>;
};

export default NavBar;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your state only handles a boolean (is open or not), but you actually need multiple booleans (one "is open or not" for each menu item). You could try something like this:

`const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState({});`

```
const handleDropdownClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const currentID = e.currentTarget.id;
    const newIsOpenState = isOpen[id] = !isOpen[id];
    setIsOpen(newIsOpenState);
};
```

And finally in your HTML:

```
const linkname = links.map((item, index) => {
    // Check to see if NavItem contains Dropdown Children
    return item.items.length > 1 ? (
        <Fragment>
            <StyledNavBar.NavLink id={index} onClick={handleDropdownClick} href={item.primary.link.url}>
               {item.primary.label[0].text}
            </StyledNavBar.NavLink>
            <Dropdown toggleOpen={isOpen[index]}>

    // ... rest of your component
```

Note the new *index* variable in the `.map` function, which is used to identify which menu item you are clicking.

**UPDATE:**

One point that I was missing was the initialization, as mention in the other answer by @MattYao. Inside your load data, do this:

```
data.then(res => {
    const navlinks = res.results[0].data.nav;
    setLinks(navlinks);
    setIsOpen(navlinks.map((link, index) => {index: false}));
});
```

---

Not related to your question, but you may want to consider [skipping effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) and including a [key](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) to your `.map`

Comment: Great!  This seems to be on the right track.  However I have a new problem but its probably something obvious I'm missing - my toggleOpen prop is now _not_ being passed down to the Dropdown component.  Any hints here?  Below is all I changed:

  `const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState([]);

  const handleDropdownClick = index => {
    const clicked = isOpen;
    clicked[index] = !clicked[index];
    setIsOpen(clicked);
  };

      <Dropdown toggleOpen={isOpen[i]}>`

(the i refers to a different index from the list map)

Comment: What do you mean by "i refers to a different index"? The index should be the same from the `.map` function. One idea is to try to print the `isOpen[i]` to see what is happening there.

Comment: I just noticed I am missing the initialization that the answer below covers it on point 2. I updated my answer to include that :)

Answer (score 0):

I can see the first two useState hooks are working as expected. The problem is your 3rd useState() hook.

The issue is pretty obvious that you are referring the same state variable isOpen by a list of elements so they all have the same state. To fix the problems, I suggest the following way:

1. Instead of having one value of isOpen, you will need to initialise the state with an array or Map so you can refer each individual one:

   ```
   const initialOpenState = [] // or using ES6 Map - new Map([]);
   ```
2. In your fetchLink function callback, initialise your isOpen state array values to be false. So you can put it here:

   ```
   data.then(res => {
      const navlinks = res.results[0].data.nav;
      setLinks(navlinks);

      // init your isOpen state here
      navlinks.forEach(link => isOpen.push({ linkId: link.id, value: false })) //I suppose you can get an id or similar identifers
    });
   ```
3. In your handleClick function, you have to target the link object and set it to true, instead of setting everything to true. You might need to use .find() to locate the link you are clicking:

   ```
   handleClick = e => {
      const currentOpenState = state;
      const clickedLink = e.target.value // use your own identifier
      currentOpenState[clickedLink].value = !currentOpenState[clickedLink].value;
      setIsOpen(currentOpenState);
   }
   ```
4. Update your component so the correct isOpen state is used:

   ```
   <Dropdown toggleOpen={isOpen[item].value}> // replace this value
      {item.items.map(subitem => {
        return (
          <StyledNavBar.NavLink href={subitem.sub_nav_link.url}>
            <span>{subitem.sub_nav_link_label[0].text}</span>
          </StyledNavBar.NavLink>
        );
      })}
    </Dropdown>
   ```

The above code may not work for you if you just copy & paste. But it should give you an idea how things should work together.